# Transferring international to international at Shanghai Pudong

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, pvg

I'll be travelling on China Eastern airlines from South Korea (ICN) to New York (JFK) next week, with a 1-hour 45-minute layover in Shanghai Pudong (PVG). From looking around on the internet a bit, I've found a lot of conflicting information about whether I'll need to re-check bags and go through immigration twice (for arriving and departing). Namely, [China Eastern's website](http://us.ceair.com/en/transLuggage.html) says that for international-to-international travel, "Whether passengers need to pick up their baggage and check in again for through-check baggage" is a no.

Anyone have any clarification/recent experience with such a trip? More generally, should 1 hour 45 minutes be enough time to get through immigration and baggage, in the worst case?

I'm aware this is similar to an older question ([International transfers at Shanghai PVG airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76461/international-transfers-at-shanghai-pvg-airport)) but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I made this new question.

Comment: Which airlines are you flying with?

Comment: sorry, just clarified, it's China Eastern

Answer (score 1):

Same airline, so your luggage will be checked in all the way to JFK. You will just transfer within T1. 1 hour and 45 minutes is plenty. This of course assumes the first flight, ICN-PVG, won't be unreasonably late [ICN and PVG are congested, and delays are the rule, rather than the exception, especially in PVG].